# Absolute continuous implies uniform continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an absolutely continuous function. Is it uniformly continuous?

I know that if $n=1$ it is true and it's called Heine's theorem, but what about $n\geq 1$?

Comment: Can you break it up by coordinate of the image?

Comment: sorry, but why is this called "Heine's theorem"? It seems to me to just be a consequence of the definition of absolute continuity

Comment: What do you mean by absolute continuity?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be absolutely continuous. Then $f$ is continuous. Since $[a,b]$ is compact by the Heine–Borel theorem, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: While this works, its also worth noting that uniform continuity is built into the definition of absolute continuity (its just a special case), so no need for Heine-Borel - the result is equally true if the domain is an open interval as well.

Comment: @MW Good point!